# How to assign Room to an Event for meeting using Microsoft Graph API in a UWP App

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am calling the API for creating a `meeting` on a `fixed date & time`. I am using `Microsoft Graph API` for this. Here is the `URL`

```
var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events";
```

I have taken care of the Authentication part and my code does the following thing to send the `JSON` response to the `API`

```
  private async void sendInvites_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var httpClient = new System.Net.Http.HttpClient();
        System.Net.Http.HttpResponseMessage response;
        var url = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events";
        CIBC.Models.SendMeetingInvites.RootObject obj = new CIBC.Models.SendMeetingInvites.RootObject();
        CIBC.Models.SendMeetingInvites.Location loc = new CIBC.Models.SendMeetingInvites.Location();
        loc.displayName = GlobalVariables.MeetingRoomName;
        //loc.RoomEmailAddress = GlobalVariables.meetingRoomEmailID.ToString();

        obj.subject = "Maths";
        CIBC.Models.SendMeetingInvites.Body body = new CIBC.Models.SendMeetingInvites.Body();
        body.content = "Its a booking for follow up meeting";
        body.contentType = "HTML";
        obj.body = body;

        List<CIBC.Models.SendMeetingInvites.Attendee> attens = new List<Models.SendMeetingInvites.Attendee>();
        for(int i=0;i<GlobalVariables.NumberOfParticipant.Count;i++)
        {
            CIBC.Models.SendMeetingInvites.EmailAddress email = new CIBC.Models.SendMeetingInvites.EmailAddress();
            CIBC.Models.SendMeetingInvites.Attendee atten = new CIBC.Models.SendMeetingInvites.Attendee();
            email.address = GlobalVariables.NumberOfParticipant[i].ParticipantADdress;
            atten.emailAddress = email;
            atten.type = "Required";
            attens.Add(atten);
        }
        CIBC.Models.SendMeetingInvites.Start start = new CIBC.Models.SendMeetingInvites.Start();
        start.dateTime = GlobalVariables.sendMeetingInviteStartDate;
        start.timeZone = "UTC";
        obj.start = start;


        CIBC.Models.SendMeetingInvites.End end = new CIBC.Models.SendMeetingInvites.End();
        end.dateTime = GlobalVariables.sendMeetingInviteEndTime;
        end.timeZone = "UTC";
        obj.end = end;
        obj.attendees = attens;
        obj.location = loc;

        string postBody = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
      //  var postBody1 = "{'Subject':'Testing Organizer - 12','Location':{'DisplayName':'Some place'}," +
      //"'Start': {'DateTime': '2016-07-15T15:00:00.0000000', 'TimeZone':'UTC'}," +
      //"'End': {'DateTime': '2016-07-15T15:30:00.0000000', 'TimeZone':'UTC'}," +
      //"'Body':{'Content': 'This is a test of Grap API.', 'ContentType':'Text'}," +
      //"'IsOrganizer':'False','Organizer':{'EmailAddress': " + "{'Address':'organizer@some.com'} }}";

        // var requestString = @"{"subject":"My event","start":{"dateTime":"2017-09-25T07:44:27.448Z","timeZone":"UTC"},"end":{"dateTime":"2017-10-02T07:44:27.448Z","timeZone":"UTC"}}"";

        var request = new System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage(System.Net.Http.HttpMethod.Post, url);
            //Add the token in Authorization header
            request.Headers.Authorization = new System.Net.Http.Headers.AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer",GlobalVariables.Token);
        request.Content = new StringContent(postBody, UTF8Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        { }
               // return await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
            else
        {

        }
                //return "";
        }
```

Here is the class file that I am using to pass to the `HTTPResponse Message`

```
namespace CIBC.Models.SendMeetingInvites
{

    public class Body
    {
        public string contentType { get; set; }
        public string content { get; set; }
    }

    public class Start
    {
        public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
        public string timeZone { get; set; }
    }

    public class End
    {
        public DateTime dateTime { get; set; }
        public string timeZone { get; set; }
    }

    public class Location
    {
        public string displayName { get; set; }
        //public string RoomEmailAddress { get; set; }
    }

    public class EmailAddress
    {
        public string address { get; set; }
        public string name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Attendee
    {
        public EmailAddress emailAddress { get; set; }
        public string type { get; set; }
    }

    public class RootObject
    {
        public string subject { get; set; }
        public Body body { get; set; }
        public Start start { get; set; }
        public End end { get; set; }
        public Location location { get; set; }
        public List<Attendee> attendees { get; set; }
    }
}
```

My requirement is to send a meeting invite to all the users and also mentioning the `Room Details like Name& Email ID of the room`.

I tried adding a RoomEmail address in the Request as under The `Location` class

```
public string RoomEmailAddress { get; set; }
```

When I tested this using `Microsoft Graph Explorer` website , i got the error message

> {
>       "error": {
>           "code": "RequestBodyRead",
>           "message": "The property 'RoomEmailAddress' does not exist on type 'Microsoft.OutlookServices.Location'. Make sure to only use
>   property names that are defined by the type or mark the type as open
>   type.",
>           "innerError": {
>               "request-id": "1883d87d-a5d6-4357-a699-7c112da0e56b",
>               "date": "2017-09-26T12:03:50"
>           }
>       } }

How do I make sure that whenever I create a `meeting request` , I can assign a `room` to it?

Currently I am just able to pass `DisplayName` while sending the `Request` to the `URL`.
Once I remove the `Email Address property (I added myself )`, the code returns `Success`.

Any workarounds so that I can send the `room email address` also so that the room also receives a copy of the `meeting invite` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the room as an attendee with `"type": "Resource"`. Then add the room's display name in the `location` property.

Comment: is there any way to search rooms based on specific location in a company?

Comment: No, not currently. The rooms API is in preview and is still very limited. This is something we're looking at improving.

Comment: Can the FindMeetingTimes API resolve availability of the rooms configured ?

Comment: Yes you can use it for that.

Comment: I am passing a parameter "resolveAvailability"=true in my JSON request to the API under the location array. Is this the right approach to address the room availability ?

Comment: Look at https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/resources/locationconstraintitem for what that parameter does. Find meeting times finds available meeting times, it doesn't list all of the free slots for an attendee or room. If that's what you're after, you should query the room's calendar directly.

Comment: would you please be helping me with the exact API to query the room for a selected date and time ? I want to extend the current meeting and looking for rooms free during the mentioned time slot

Comment: A calendar view on the room's calendar with start set to the beginning of the window and end set to the end should do it, right? https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_list_calendarview

Comment: Would you be able to answer this one ? I am struck  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46703193/findmeetingtimes-api-not-returning-expected-output-for-the-same-date?noredirect=1#comment80438211_46703193