# FindMeetingTimes API not returning expected output for the same date

Tags: c#, uwp, microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I am using the *`FindMeetingTimes`* API of Microsoft Graph Library. I am sending the request

```
{  
   "attendees":[  
      {  
         "emailAddress":{  
            "address":"aparna@meetingassistant.onmicrosoft.com",
            "name":"Aparna Banerjee"
         },
         "type":"Required"
      },
      {  
         "emailAddress":{  
            "address":"pallavi01@meetingassistant.onmicrosoft.com",
            "name":"Pallavi Chowdhery"
         },
         "type":"Required"
      }
   ],
   "timeConstraint":{  
      "timeslots":[  
         {  
            "start":{  
               "dateTime":"2017-10-12T18:00:00",
               "timeZone":"India Standard Time"
            },
            "end":{  
               "dateTime":"2017-10-12T19:00:00",
               "timeZone":"India Standard Time"
            }
         }
      ],
      "activityDomain":"work"
   },
   "locationConstraint":{  
      "isRequired":true,
      "suggestLocation":false,
      "locations":[  
         {  
            "displayName":"Room 101",
            "locationEmailAddress":"Meetingroom101@meetingassistant.onmicrosoft.com",
            "resolveAvailability":"true"
         },
         {  
            "displayName":"Room 303",
            "locationEmailAddress":"meetingroom303@meetingassistant.onmicrosoft.com",
            "resolveAvailability":"true"
         },
         {  
            "displayName":"Room 402",
            "locationEmailAddress":"meetingroom402@meetingassistant.onmicrosoft.com",
            "resolveAvailability":"true"
         },
         {  
            "displayName":"Room 007",
            "locationEmailAddress":"meetingroom007@meetingassistant.onmicrosoft.com",
            "resolveAvailability":"true"
         }
      ]
   },
   "meetingDuration":"PT30M",
   "returnSuggestionReasons":"true",
   "minimumAttendeePercentage":"100"
}
```

My problem is for the `selected Date & Time` , The API is giving me response like this

```
{  
   "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.meetingTimeSuggestionsResult",
   "emptySuggestionsReason":"Unknown",
   "meetingTimeSuggestions":[  

   ]
}
```

and sometimes I also get `AttendeesUnavailable`.
If I go ahead and change the `end date` to the next day or greater. I get the proper responses.

I want to utilize this `API` to look out for rooms incase I want to extend my `current meeting`. 
**Example** 
I have a currently ongoing meeting for another 30 minutes. I want to extend that meeting for some more time

```
(time would be passed via the parameter).
```

I want to look out for the availability of rooms as well as participants.

**UPDATE**

I changed the parameter

```
"activityDomain":"work"
```

to

```
 "activityDomain":"unrestricted"
```

I checked the `Organizer's` `calendar` for the day (screenshot attached). Only one meeting configured for the day [image]

I am trying to get the availability for him . Check the JSON Request below

```
{  
       "attendees":[  
          {  
             "emailAddress":{  
                "address":"aparna@meetingassistant.onmicrosoft.com",
                "name":"Aparna Banerjee"
             },
             "type":"Required"
          },
          {  
             "emailAddress":{  
                "address":"pallavi01@meetingassistant.onmicrosoft.com",
                "name":"Pallavi Chowdhery"
             },
             "type":"Required"
          }
       ],
       "timeConstraint":{  
          "timeslots":[  
             {  
                "start":{  
                   "dateTime":"2017-10-12T16:32:00",
                   "timeZone":"India Standard Time"
                },
                "end":{  
                   "dateTime":"2017-10-12T17:06:00",
                   "timeZone":"India Standard Time"
                }
             }
          ],
          "activityDomain":"unrestricted"
       },
       "locationConstraint":{  
          "isRequired":true,
          "suggestLocation":false,
          "locations":[  
             {  
                "displayName":"Room 101",
                "locationEmailAddress":"Meetingroom101@meetingassistant.onmicrosoft.com",
                "resolveAvailability":"true"
             },
             {  
                "displayName":"Room 303",
                "locationEmailAddress":"meetingroom303@meetingassistant.onmicrosoft.com",
                "resolveAvailability":"true"
             },
             {  
                "displayName":"Room 402",
                "locationEmailAddress":"meetingroom402@meetingassistant.onmicrosoft.com",
                "resolveAvailability":"true"
             },
             {  
                "displayName":"Room 007",
                "locationEmailAddress":"meetingroom007@meetingassistant.onmicrosoft.com",
                "resolveAvailability":"true"
             }
          ]
       },
       "meetingDuration":"PT30M",
       "returnSuggestionReasons":"true",
       "minimumAttendeePercentage":"100"
    }
```

The `response` I got was

```
{
   "@odata.context":"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#microsoft.graph.meetingTimeSuggestionsResult",
   "emptySuggestionsReason":"OrganizerUnavailable",
   "meetingTimeSuggestions":[

   ]
}
```

I want to know why its showing a problem in the getting the `suggestions` ? Provided The `Organizer` doesn't have any meetings for the day.

Comment: Do either of the attendees have meetings at this time? Are there any meetings scheduled for the locations you requested?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT No , nothing of this sort. All these attendees are free during the time duration. I donot know why this output then ?

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-Microsoft Any updates for me ?

Comment: I'm unable to replicate. Have you tried removing constraints to narrow down which one isn't working as expected?

Comment: I want to look out for extending a meeting. Let's take a scenrio where I am having a meeting from 4 pm to 4.30 PM. I want to extend the meeting from 4.31 to 5.00 PM . I want to know the room availability for the organization ( I have configured the room in the request header) and all the participants from the previous meeting are carry forwarded . Even the organizer is available at that time but the API is not giving results and throwing responses like orgsnizer not available or Attendees Unavailable .why ?

Comment: Can you get response headers from a request that isn't behaving as you expect? This will help us investigate.

Comment: The one in the question might help ?

Comment: Based on another [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198233/unable-to-set-isorganizeroptional-parameter-in-findmeetingtimes), I suspect the issue here may be related to the time `2017-10-12T16:32:00`. I have found a couple of reports that times other than the top of the hour (`16:00`)  or at the half-hour (`16:30`) are resulting in `"emptySuggestionsReason":"OrganizerUnavailable"`.

Comment: @Apoorv, check out my two posts: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48214744/findmeetingtimes-thows-organizerunavailable-on-15-minute-start-times, and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48198233/unable-to-set-isorganizeroptional-parameter-in-findmeetingtimes MS is suggesting, that this may be a bug.

Comment: Indeed this is a bug. Is there any bounty program where I can push it ?