# Bug: findMeetingTimes throws "OrganizerUnavailable" on 15 minute start times

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-restapi

When using the Graph API findMeetingTimes method on 15 minute start times (for example 3:15, or 3:45), the method will incorrectly throw a "emptySuggestionsReason = OrganizerUnavailable" error (and no rooms returned), whether rooms are available for that time, or not.

For example, this will error:

```
{
"timeConstraint": {
"timeslots": [
  {
    "start": {
      "dateTime": "2018-01-11T10:15:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
      "dateTime": "2018-01-11T11:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    }
  }
]...}
```

Whereas, this will not:

```
{
"timeConstraint": {
"timeslots": [
  {
    "start": {
      "dateTime": "2018-01-11T10:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    },
    "end": {
      "dateTime": "2018-01-11T11:00:00",
      "timeZone": "Pacific Standard Time"
    }
  }
]...}
```

Note the `"2018-01-11T10:15:00"` start time.

UPDATE 1:

This appears to have been resolved, by setting the `meetingDuration` value: a) in 15 minute increments, and b) to the exact legnth of the proposed meeting, for example `"meetingDuration": "PT45M"`.

UPDATE 2:

This issue is still not fully resolved: 1) There is now the ability to find 15 minute segments using `"meetingDuration": "PT15M"`, BUT 2) NOT if the 15 minute segment butts up against an upcoming meeting.

For example, if the room has a pre-existing meeting at 1pm, the time option of 12:30 - 1:00pm can be found, the time of 12:30 - 12:45pm can be found, BUT the time of 12:45pm - 1:00pm still throws the error of `"emptySuggestionsReason": "OrganizerUnavailable"`.

This is even using the option `"activityDomain":"unrestricted"`.

Can someone at Microsoft please address this issue?

Comment: This issue has been resolved by Microsoft.

Comment: no, this issue is not resolved, I am still facing the same issue over the 15-minute duration